# Can't control select option when setup firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I am learning Firebase Cloud Firestore. I get a problem.
when run command line: firebase init.

```
Screen appears to select:
>( ) Database: Deploy Firebase Realtime Database Rules
 ( ) Firestore: Deploy rules and create indexes for Firestore
 ( ) Functions: Configure and deploy Cloud Functions
 ( ) Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites
 ( ) Storage: Deploy Cloud Storage security rules
 ( ) Emulators: Set up local emulators for Firebase features
```

But I can't select. Because My cursor still shows like this.

[image]
 how to solve that? I use window 10

Comment: If you have a bug to report with the Firebase CLI, post it as an issue on the project GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 0):

You are using strange command prompt, at least unknown to me. I think you could use standard Windows `cmd` or "Windows Powershell". Both are working fine on my side.

I hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

use spacebar to select, it works : )